# exsl:document - trying to generate output file

Tags: xslt, output

I have this code so far: - now updated with different code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:variable name="emailPID" select="attr[@tag='00100020']"/>
  <xsl:variable name="emailPName" select="attr[@tag='00100010']"/>
  <!-- overwritten by application with actual values -->
  <xsl:param name="calling" select="'SAMPLE_MOD'"/>
  <xsl:param name="called" select="'SERVER1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="date" select="'20051206'"/>
  <xsl:param name="time" select="'115600.000'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/dataset">
    <exsl:document href="file:///c|/apps/foo.txt">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$emailPID"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$emailPName"/>
    </exsl:document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformer doesn't throw any errors that I see, but I cannot see the "c:\apps\foo.txt" file I am expecting either.  Is there some formatting wrong here or am I leaving something out?

thank you for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processor should throw an error when it sees

```
extension-element-prefixes="exslt"
```

because the prefix "exslt" has not been declared. Perhaps you meant "exsl". At present, "exsl" is not declared as an extension namespace, therefore "exsl:document" is a simple literal result element rather than an instruction.

Comment: I have updated the code above and I am seeing an error now of:  Unrecognized XSLTC extension 'http://exslt.org/common:document'.  Can I only use "exsl:document" if I register/add it to my XSLT Engine?

Comment: Very few processors allow you to implement your own extension instructions. It is very likely that this particular extension is not available for your chosen processor. If you are using XSLTC then you are presumably using Java, so your best strategy is to adopt XSLT 2.0 (in the form of Saxon) and use the standard xsl:result-document instruction.

Comment: I think I'll try to install SaxonHE in Jboss 4 - thanks for taking the time, your answers were very informative.

Answer (score 1):

[The `href` attribute of an `exsl:document` needs to be a valid URI](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/). The XSLT engine is probably confusing the part before the colon (i.e. `c`) as a [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), not part of the path.

If you are using an absolute address for the filesystem, include the [`file:` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme):

```
<exsl:document href="file:///c:\apps\foo.txt">
```

The drive colon ad slashes may cause problems on non-windows platforms so you can instead try:

```
<exsl:document href="file:///c|/apps/foo.txt">
```